# Is exponential of a concave function concave?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

is this function:

$$\exp\Big(-||Ax||^2\Big)$$

concave in A??

I know that exponential of a convex function is convex, but is exponential of a concave function concave??

Comment: Surely you checked that $x\mapsto\mathrm e^{-x^2}$ is convex or concave (it is neither).

Comment: don't get it ...ORz

Comment: In general, composing a concave function with an exponential doesn't produce a concave function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Did's example

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Then $f'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2}$, so $f''(x)=4x^2e^{-x^2}-2e^{-x^2}=(4x^2-2)e^{-x^2}$.

$e^{-x^2}$ is always positive, but $4x^2-2$ can be positive or negative.